# Apache Spark on Kubernetes (Docker for Mac) is not able resolve my VPN hosts

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to submit a job via Kubernetes. Went through https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html and successfully submit a job via below command:

```
$ bin/spark-submit \
--master k8s://https://<k8s-apiserver-host>:<k8s-apiserver-port> \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name spark-pi \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--conf spark.executor.instances=5 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=<spark-image> \
local:///path/to/examples.jar
```

Now, I am trying to submit my job which involves Kafka & PostgreSQL access of which is available over the VPN.

The job works on my local via IntelliJ but the same job fails when I try to submit to Kubernetes.

Exception is

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: db-host-name
```

How can I resolve DNS name over the VPN?

[image]
[image: IP is xx]

Comment: Please provide more information about your Kubernetes cluster. Is it minikube instance on your own machine or is it something else? Does your Kubernetes cluster and local machine have the same DNS servers configured?

Comment: I am using docker on mac.

Comment: I have attached pictures. I also tried to set the DNS but it's not working.

Comment: Are you able to connect from your Kubernetes pod to your DB Host by IP address? Will this IP address be static one or will it change periodically?

Comment: From Kubernetes, I am able to ping the IP but not the DNS. The IP is static. @Dawid Kruk

Answer (score 0):

If you can trying configuring the dns options for the docker image. Either of these two options have worked for DNS/VPN issues I've experienced in the past:

- `--dns=<IP_ADDRESS>`
- `--dns-search=<DOMAIN>`

Here's more detailed [docs](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/)

Comment: But this is for the Docker, do you know how to do the same trick on Kubernetes?